# Should the tag interpretation be deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [interpretation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation) seems to provide no value to the taxonomy. Besides the fact, that *Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature* are considered off-topic, the questions seem to be either arbitrarily tagged ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348825/what-is-the-difference-between-get-back-to-your-box-and-get-back-in-your-box), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315437/are-there-previous-formulations-of-this-quote-from-george-r-r-martin), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303868/singular-or-plural-the-whole-of-a-b-is-are), ...), [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) questions ([4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308671/how-should-a-month-and-ten-days-from-now-be-interpreted),[5](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127608/what-does-the-initial-fragment-of-the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy-mean), ...) or actual off-topic poetry interpretations ([6](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340372/in-the-poem-green-beret-by-ho-thien-is-this-line-considered-as-using-irony),[7](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325529/a-swift-execution-on-a-morning-mortal-with-light-petrified), ...).

I suggest to make [interpretation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation) a synonym of [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

I went ahead and made the suggestion in the system.
[Four votes are needed](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/meaning/synonyms)

The synonym is in place. Topic closed.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: You're right that interpretation is not a useful tag, but then, neither is meaning! meaning should probably be made a synonym of meaning-in-context just so that it's clear when it's appropriate to use.

Comment: @curiousdannii That should be a different question. One that I see quite a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synonym is in place. Topic closed. I will accept this to keep it from bumping up again.